# Binding key for clean project command in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want to bind a key for clean project so it wont be necessary any more to pres right click an then find the command clean project from the drop-down menu. I want to do that simply by key binding combination. Excuse my bad English. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a shortcut in `Preferences Dialog > General > Keys`.

Type `clean` in the text field to filter the commands and select `Build Clean` command. Then move focus to `Binding:` field and press the keys you want to bind to the command.

[image]